# SmtpClient in C# when need to load Configurations in code not app.config

Tags: smtpclient

I have a function in my class to send emails using SmtpClient.

```
public void Send(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail)
    {      
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {                
            client.Host = ConfigReader.SmtpHost;
            client.Port = ConfigReader.SmtpPort;
            client.EnableSsl = ConfigReader.SmtpEnableSsl;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = ConfigReader.SmtpDefaultCredentials;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigReader.SmtpUserName, ConfigReader.SmtpPassword);

            client.Send(mail);
        }            
    }
```

I need to set Smtp configs using another class in this function. But it does not seem right to set configuration every time this function is called.

What's the better approach for this? If I load the configuration in some other Init function to be called only once, how would SmtpClient will be disposed off in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You create your `SmtpClient` object locally and more over in `using` statement as the object disposes out of scope your function. You must configure your object every time when you create them.

Comment: Why we should not have SmtpClient object on class level? Configuring the object every time Send is called does not seem to be efficient.

Comment: You can have object in class level. The lifetime of the object will be depends to lifetime of your class. If you don't want to have long life object you must use code as in your OP.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages in case of a long life SmtpClient object? I plan to wrap it in a class library to be used by a service. The user application or applications can ask the service to send email at any time. How should I manage the object lifetime in this case?